# How to create Custom Build in Titanium

Tags: build, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

In Resource folder I have a folder that contains many JS files. so while building the Application can I someway edit the build so that the only files which I need at that time should build rest of the files will be ignored. Is this possible in Titanium

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found out that was applying resource filter on the project. But that is the manual task.
By applying the resource filter only the selected resources will get build and rest will be ignored..